# relaxing maths papers

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am looking for some relaxing, funny maths article that one can read when tired. For instance, I found Bouton's paper "Nim, a game with a complete mathematical theory" very funny. If you know something similar, like articles dealing with simple games that you can play with friends, or with a combinatorial theory that you can write down in a C program, or any other amusing aspect of mathematics that does not require a huge background and that you can read when you are very tired, but not too much tired to give it up, I would be grateful if you could share it!

Thank you,
bye!

Comment: I would recommend almost anything by Martin Gardner.

Comment: Since you asked for funny: I'm fond of [this one](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/mathmajor/archive/catchlion.pdf)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As one of the nicest series of (often)  relaxing articles I found the following of Ed. Sandifer about tools, tricks and considerations of L. Euler : http://www.maa.org/news/howeulerdidit.html

Answer (score 6):

Raymond Smullyan has some awesome puzzle books.  You might want to check out "What is the Name of This Book" or "This Book Needs No Title".

Answer (score 3):

Almost any article from Princeton Companion to Mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the *Mathematical Intelligencer*.  Some of what they publish fits this description; other things don't.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this paper](http://math.ucr.edu/~huerta/strangest.pdf) recently. It is about the octonions and their role in string theory, and how they may provide an answer to why our universe might have 10 dimensions. This is a very fun paper to read and does not require much in the way of physics.